# how to enable my shortcut key as previous versions?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I just want to use shortcut key as before versions i.e. when i press alt+space it gives us options like minimize, unmaximize, move etc... but they are not working with keys like 'n'  for minimize 'c' for close etc.. as our previous versions.

Comment: Could you better describe what sequence of keys you mean to type, and what actions do you want to get?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Ubuntu 20, there are shortcuts for minimizing/restoring/maximizing windows: <Win>+<Up>, <Win>+<Down>, <Win>+H.
Plus other shortcuts.
I am not sure this goes exactly the way you had in mind, but it may be useful.
See

[image]